# Spring Boot Hibernate Validator Exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I using hibernate validator to validate my entity before save

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Selo>> error = validator.validate(seloNovo);
```

So. It's possible to throw that error just like when I put a @Valid in my Controller?

something like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-08-27T16:57:16.386+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotEmpty.atoRtdpj.sgTabelaCustas",
                "NotEmpty.sgTabelaCustas",
                "NotEmpty.java.lang.String",
                "NotEmpty"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "atoRtdpj.sgTabelaCustas",
                        "sgTabelaCustas"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "sgTabelaCustas",
                    "code": "sgTabelaCustas"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "must not be empty",
            "objectName": "atoRtdpj",
            "field": "sgTabelaCustas",
            "rejectedValue": null,
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotEmpty"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Validation failed for object='atoRtdpj'. Error count: 1",
    "path": "/selo/RTDPJ/" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare this beans.

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean(name = "validator")
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return localValidatorFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    MethodValidationPostProcessor validationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    validationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
    return validationPostProcessor;
}
```

Save your messages in src/main/resources/messages and name them as follow: messages_en_US.properties. Of course, you can have more than one language.

My spring-boot version is 1.5.12.RELEASE.

Comment: Only to use validator.validate() he will throw the exception or I need to throw? and how

Comment: The valid and validate annotation will process your object and will throw the exception(ConstraintViolationException) for you.